# Airtable ntegration with next does not work in production but works locally

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, airtable

I have the following code:

```
"use server";

import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { z } from "zod";
import Airtable from 'airtable';

Airtable
  .configure({
    apiKey: 'PAT KEY'
  })
Airtable
  .base('ID');

export async function registerSignUp(prevState: { message: string; }, formData: FormData,) {
  const schema = z.object({
    email: z.string(),
  });
  const parse = schema.safeParse({
    email: formData.get("email"),
  });

  if (!parse.success) {
    return { message: "Failed to sign up" };
  }

  const data = parse.data;

  try {
    await Airtable.Table.create(data);

    revalidatePath("/");
    return { message: `Signed Up!` };
  } catch (e) {
    return { message: "Failed to sign up" };
  }
}
```

So all of the above, obvs with the PAT key and ID added works locally but not on production.

I am using Vercel free tier to host my site and wonder if that is the problem. Or on airtable there is some CORS or domain whitelisting somewhere.

UPDATE:

after adding a console log for the error thrown in the catch block, I got:

```
TypeError: Expected signal to be an instanceof AbortSignal
    at new q (/var/task/dist/apps/fe/brochure/.next/server/chunks/838.js:5:131465)
    at /var/task/dist/apps/fe/brochure/.next/server/chunks/838.js:5:132911
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.X [as default] (/var/task/dist/apps/fe/brochure/.next/server/chunks/838.js:5:132863)
    at Object.e [as default] (/var/task/dist/apps/fe/brochure/.next/server/chunks/838.js:1:21616)
    at e.runAction (/var/task/dist/apps/fe/brochure/.next/server/chunks/838.js:1:10849)
    at e._createRecords (/var/task/dist/apps/fe/brochure/.next/server/chunks/838.js:1:24092)
    at /var/task/dist/apps/fe/brochure/.next/server/chunks/838.js:1:13135
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.create (/var/task/dist/apps/fe/brochure/.next/server/chunks/838.js:1:13072)
```